# Setting values for an array of UILabels which in turn is in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of UILabels as follows:

```
@interface ClueLabels : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1, *label2, *label3, *label4, *label5, *label6, *label7, *label8;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *labels;

+ (ClueLabels *)clueLabels;

- (void)labelsDidLoad;

@end
```

Which is implemented as a singleton:

```
@implementation ClueLabels

@synthesize label1 = _label1;
@synthesize label2 = _label2;
@synthesize label3 = _label3;
@synthesize label4 = _label4;
@synthesize label5 = _label5;
@synthesize label6 = _label6;
@synthesize label7 = _label7;
@synthesize label8 = _label8;

@synthesize labels = _labels;

+ (ClueLabels *)clueLabels {
    static ClueLabels *singleton;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        singleton = [[ClueLabels alloc] init];
    });
    return singleton;
}

- (void)labelsDidLoad {
    _labels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_label1, _label2, _label3, _label4, _label5, _label6, _label7, _label8, nil];
    NSLog(@"Clue labels did load");
}

@end
```

Then stored in an NSMutableDictionary as follows:

```
 NSMutableArray *keyArray;
 NSMutableArray *valueArray;
 keyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"answerButtons", @"clueLabels", nil];
 valueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [AnswerButtons answerButtons], [ClueLabels clueLabels], nil];

 NSMutableDictionary *externals = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valueArray
                                                       forKeys:keyArray];
```

Now I want to write to the labels (for instance, to clear them), but they are buried in a singleton and stored as an array inside key-valued dictionary.  Conceptually, I need to send a message to one object in the dictionary using key-value syntax, and then loop over the objects in that array, clearing them with setText@"" for instance.  Is this a nested message with a loop?  I can't quite figure out how to structure this task.  Thank you.

EDIT:  I got to thinking and decided (maybe incorrectly) that because the labels are in a singleton, I don't need to access them through the dictionary at all, I just need to access the singleton and the dictionary will be updated automatically.  So I decided my question/problem is more "how to talk to my singleton".  I looked around SO some and then figured out I could do something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [ClueLabels clueLabels].labels)
```

Which returns the details of each label.  I'd like to be able to get the count of labels so I can loop over them and set their titles to arbitrary strings.  Can I build around [ClueLabels clueLabels].labels or do I need a different approach?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

U can either loop on the UILabels as u said. Or u can use "makeObjectsPerformSelector" method on the array, which will (as its name says) make all the objects in it perform the selector u sent. Thus saves the looping part. But either way u need to get a hold of the array of labels contained in the dictionary

Comment: Thanks.  I guess my question was really about the last part "...get ahold of the array of labels contained in the dictionary.  See edit to original question.

Answer (score 0):

Mission accomplished!  Here's how I did it:

```
// Clear the fields

for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++) {
    UILabel *l = [[ClueLabels clueLabels].labels objectAtIndex:idx];
    [l setText:@""];
```

Obviously, I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
   for (UILabel *theLabel in clueLabels)
   {
   [theLabel setText:@"];
   }
```